# When I install any version of Ubuntu on my laptop, I get the following error, and Ubuntu will not boot. Does anyone know how to resolve?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi

Here is the error:

```
8.388165] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.PB2),
RE HOT_FOTHD (20221020/dswload2-162)
.388197) ACPI Error: RE_NOT_FOUND, During nane lookup/catalog (20221020/ps
L
object-220)
8.3882511 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIØ.PB2),
I
RE.HOT. FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)
B.386254) ACPI ErTor: RE_HOT_ FOUND, During nane lookup/catalog (20221020/ps
object-220)
3.170858] hub 6-8:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
```

I'm dual booting along side Windows 11 pro, two separate ssd's. Device specs: Lenovo 5 Pro, AMD Ryzen 7 6800H with Radeon graphics 3.20 GHz 32 GB RAM

This is a new error, never came up in previous iterations of Ubuntu. I've tried Vanilla Ubuntu, and Kubuntu. The installation process goes fine, then when I try to boot in I get that error. I can't get past that screen, unless I use recovery mode, which does work but then I can't really use because I can't use my monitors and peripherals.

What I've done: I've run a full device scan from UEFI, took like 7 hours all passed. Tried using a different USB to install. Installed opensuse to see if it's all distro's, it worked, but was insanely slow.